# Python Pandas - Read CSV or Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm allowing users to upload a CSV or Excel file. I'm using pandas to read the file and create a dataframe. Since I can't predict which filetype the user will upload, I wrapped pd.read_csv() and pd.read_excel() in a try/except block.

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    input_filename = secure_filename(form.file.data.filename)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(form.file.data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
    except:
        df = pd.read_excel(form.file.data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
```

If pd.read_csv() is first in the try/except block and I upload a .csv file it works. If I attempt to upload a .xlsx file, I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

If pd.read_excel() is first in the try/except block and I upload an .xlsx file it works. If I attempt to upload a .csv file, I get this error:

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Previously, I used mimetype to route the file to the correct pandas function, but I was hoping for a cleaner (and all encompassing) solution that didn't involve several if/elif statements. This is what I had:

```
if form.file.data.mimetype == 'text/csv':
    df = pd.read_csv(form.file.data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
elif form.file.data.mimetype == 'application/octet-stream':
    df = pd.read_excel(form.file.data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
elif form.file.data.mimetype == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
    df = pd.read_excel(form.file.data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
else:
    flash('Error Uploading File. Invalid file type. Please use xls, xlsx or csv.', 'danger')
    return render_template('upload.html', current_user=current_user, form=form)
```

I'm using Flask, WTForms and Python 3. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with wtforms, so..., what is `form.file.data`? If its a file-like object, is there a way to seek back to position 0? If not, you may need to read it into something like an `io.StringIO` buffer that can be rewound. Then, when the read fails, seek to 0 before trying the second type.

Comment: You may also need to figure out the encoding for the csv file. That's the advantage of using the http headers like you were doing before.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `read_excel` with keyword args that are useful for `read_csv` but not supported by `read_excel`. Instead you might try:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    input_filename = secure_filename(form.file.data.filename)
    data = form.file.data
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, skip_blank_lines=True, 
                         skipinitialspace=True, encoding='latin-1')
    except:
        df = pd.read_excel(data, header=0)
```

In addition to removing the extra args to `read_excel`, I've also hoisted extracting the data out of `form.file.data`; this is combat the possibility that that there could be some lazy-load behavior interacting poorly with the `try`/`except` block.

In general it is hard to debug moderately complex I/O functions in the midst of web requests. When operations like this don't work, best approach is to split the problem into two parts: 1/ Get data from the web request, write it to a file. Then separately, 2/ try the I/O (in this case, Pandas dataframe load) from the resulting file. Doing this interactively or in a separate program will give you more debugging opportunities and clarity. [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) is excellent for such exploratory tests, though most IDEs or even the bare Python REPL will work. When part 2/ is clearly working, then you can patch it back in under the Flask / web app code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your code, but there still seems to be an issue when the file format corresponds to the pandas read function in the except clause. It appears that when an exception is raised after trying to read the data into a dataframe in the try clause that the form.file.data becomes None. Could this be a lazy-load issue?

Comment: It could. Some data sources are "exhaustible." Generators, for example, And files, to an extent (though they have a seek method that lets you go back to the beginning). Recommend you write data to a file before the `try`/`except`. Examine it. Is there a way to conditionalize which pd read method you used based on the data? "Get forgiveness not permission" not always best, if the data read is not idempotent.

Comment: I decided to use filename.endswith('.csv') as a way to route the files to the correct pd read method. Thank you for the help!